# iOS: How to animate hiding in a UITableCell "delete" menu after a confirmation dialog?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a cell delete handle function that alerts a confirmation dialog, and if the user presses "Okay", it will go ahead and delete the cell. Otherwise, I want it to programmatically hide the delete button. I have the following function set up to handle deleting a UITableView cell in my UITableViewDelegate:

```
// delete a cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(editingStyle == .Delete) {
        var deleteAlert = UIAlertController(
            title: "Delete?",
            message: "All data will be permanently deleted.",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        deleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: {
            (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            // delete logic here:
            self.deleteDataForCell(indexPath.row)
            self.myTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            println("Delete successful")
        }))
        deleteAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {
            (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            println("Delete cancelled")
            // TODO - now hide the delete button with animation
        }))
        presentViewController(deleteAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The "TODO" part is where I don't know how to force the table to hide the delete button programatically. Right now the delete button will just stay in view until the user taps elsewhere on the screen. I can call `myTable.reloadData()` but that isn't animated.

Comment: Have you tried `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [AnyObject], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)`?

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't quite work exactly how I hoped. It will animate the entire cell as described here: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewRowAnimation but it doesn't "undo" the slide-in animation. None of the options allowed for the same default animation you would get for tapping elsewhere on the screen.

Comment: I looked into it in a little more detail.  When the cell displays the delete confirmation button, it adds a gesture recogniser to the cell.  When the user taps outside the button, this recogniser calls a private method on the cell, which causes it to animate back and remove the delete confirmation button.  So you may have to live with a messy workaround.

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution using this:

```
self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
```